# How convert é -> e, š -> s, ė -> e , ą -> a ... in javascript?

Tags: javascript, multilingual

I have a string like `Brazil: Série A` my goal is to convert to `Brazil: Serie A`.

Also, method should convert and other similar situations:
é -> e, š -> s, ė -> e , ą -> a ...

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815883/convert-non-ascii-characters-umlauts-accents-to-their-closest-ascii-equiva, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123501/replacing-accented-characters-with-plain-ascii-ones

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing accented characters with plain ascii ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123501/replacing-accented-characters-with-plain-ascii-ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Slugify (https://github.com/simov/slugify) to do just that. It comes with a predefined set of characters it will replace with plain english ones https://github.com/simov/slugify/blob/master/index.js#L13 and the ability to extend it.