# Convert Special Quoations to Normal Quoations

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, ascii, converters

So i saw this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815883/convert-non-ascii-characters-umlauts-accents-to-their-closest-ascii-equiva) which talks about converting non-ASCII characters to their closest ASCII equivalent. The given solution is:

```
var str = "Rånades på Skyttis i Ö-vik";
var combining = /[\u0300-\u036F]/g; 

console.log(str.normalize('NFKD').replace(combining, ''));
```

Now my issue is similar but not the same. I am looking at replacing special characters like **[Left Double Quotation Mark](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/left-double-quotation-mark/)** which is hex `&#x201C;` or entity `&ldquo;`. The problem is that i can't use the hex code, html entity or any form of encoding. I need to replace special characters like this with their closest standard UTF-8 Character like a normal [**Double Quotation Mark**](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/quotation-mark/). The reason being is that the final product is going into an email subject line and no encoding can be present there on some clients, so i'm looking for a JS solution.

It can't be a straight mapping either because it might not be a quotation mark, it could be any kind of symbol. Like an mdash which needs to become a normal dash.

Comment: why do you assume there is an appropriate ascii character?  Without a mapping, I think this is going to be essentially impossible.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet If i do a mapping there is always the potential to miss something. I assumed, maybe there is a js library that already has a mapping out there which covers 99% of characters.

Comment: Unicode is *large*. What would be your candidate ASCII character for [:pile-of-poo:](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f4a9)?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet no emoji's, just stuff that's usually used in essays, stories, news articles, etc.

Comment: But the point is that as far as I know there is no definitive list of that "stuff".  I think you probably need to start collecting a list of the ones that matter to you.  Almost certainly others have done so, and you might be able to find such a list online.  But I've never seen one.